# GORM in Griffon

Tags: spring, plugins, grails-orm, griffon

im just trying out griffon, just wanna ask if is it possible to perform *GORM* in a griffon application? Do I need to install an additional plugin to make it possible?
thanks for those who want to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to use GORM with Griffon however the path to get it to work is not as smooth as you would assume, coming from Grails. Do a web search for "standalone GORM" and you'll get some results like this one http://www.grails.org/GORM+-+StandAlone+Gorm

Now, Griffon sports quite a number of persistence plugins, just have a look at http://artifacts.griffon-framework.org/tags/plugin/persistence. Most of them provide a low level data access API, however some are lightweight ORM solutions, like Carbonado, ActiveJDBC, MyBatis and even EBean.

Comment: oh i see.. thanks for responding. one more question, I'm having a problem in installing plugins in my griffon app. everytime i tried to install a plugin this error always appears: _Failed to install plugin miglayout [offline: false]_ I thought that my proxy configuration is the cause of this problem but i also tried it in our home that doesn't require proxy settings to connect to the internet and i still got the same result, it failed to install. can you tell me what may be the cause of this problem? thanks for sharing your knowledge. im using griffon 1.0.0

Comment: This is likely a network problem of some sort. You can obtain a better error message that can help you pinpoint the exact problem by tweaking the logging options in griffon-app/conf/BuidConfig.groovy. Make sure you set 'org.codehaus.griffon' to trace.